# How do I find full path to an application in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I in a batch script find the full path to application XYZ if it is installed

Clarifications:

1. The application is not in the PATH
2. All I have is it's name in this case "ISTool.exe" and I would like to get **C:\Program\ISTool\ISTool.exe**

Comment: Could you please clarify your task? Do you want, say, to get "C:\Program Files\iTunes" given "iTunes" as an input?

Comment: So, as an input you want to give "ISTool.exe" and it's not in the path?  You'd have to search the whole drive for it. -- `dir c:\ISTool.exe /s /b` -- you can pipe the output to wherever, but if the file comes up more than once you'll have multiple lines to deal with -- also, if the user has more than one drive you may need to scan all of them (not sure the best way to get all drives, maybe a WMI query for non-removable drives...) -- but this could take ages, even with SSD -- you're better off scanning 5 or 6 known locations including %ProgramFiles%\ISTool\ and %ProgramFiles(x86)%\ISTool, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers I got from others worked (but slow or used extra files) and worked for any exe but didn't really suit my needs.

Since I wanted to find a particular exe I went looking in the registry using [REG QUERY](http://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/cc742028%28WS.10%29.aspx) instead. I found a key that contained the data I wanted to find and extracted that.

The result is fast, has few lines of code but is not very pretty nor reusable.

Short example:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
set found=
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\ISTool.exe\shell\OpenWithISTool\command"') DO (
 set found=%%c
)

for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a in ("%found%") do (
 set my_exe=%%a
)
echo %my_exe%
ENDLOCAL
```

This results in `"C:\Program\ISTool\ISTool.exe"` (with quotes)
**Note**: delims= above is followed by a tab-char

Answer (score 32):

You can locate an executable on the path (or other path-like string if necessary):

```
c:\> for %i in (cmd.exe) do @echo. %~$PATH:i
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

c:\> for %i in (python.exe) do @echo. %~$PATH:i
C:\Python25\python.exe
```

Details can be found at the end of the help text for the `"for"` command, `"for /?"` but the summary is:

```
%~i    - expands %i removing any surrounding quotes.
%~fi   - expands %i to a fully qualified path name.
%~di   - expands %i to a drive letter only.
%~pi   - expands %i to a path only.
%~ni   - expands %i to a file name only.
%~xi   - expands %i to a file extension only.
%~si   - expanded path contains short names only.
%~ai   - expands %i to file attributes of file.
%~ti   - expands %i to date/time of file.
%~zi   - expands %i to size of file.
%~$P:i - searches the directories listed in the P environment variable
         and expands %i to the fully qualified name of the first one found.
         If the environment variable name is not defined or the file is not
         found by the search, then this modifier expands to the empty string.
```

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```
%~dpi    - expands %i to a drive letter and path only.
%~nxi    - expands %i to a file name and extension only.
%~fsi    - expands %i to a full path name with short names only.
%~dp$P:i - searches the directories listed in the P environment variable
           for %i and expands to the drive letter and path of the first
           one found.
%~ftzai  - expands %i to a DIR like output line.
```

If your executable isn't on the path (as per your edit), your best bet is to use the bare/subdirectory format of `dir` which will do it for you. From the root directory:

```
dir /b /s ISTool.exe
```

will get you all of the files on that drive with that name. You then just have to parse the output. My own preference would be to use Cygwin's `"find /cygdrive -name ISTool.exe"` but that's because I already have it installed. You may not want that (or even have that option).

*Update:*

That `dir /b /s` command will take a while since it's basically searching the whole disk. If that's a problem you may want to consider periodically creating a cached record of all files on all disks with a cmd file like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
del c:\files.cache.tmp >nul: 2>nul:
for %%d in (c d e) do (
    cd /d %%d:\
    dir /b /s >>c:\files.cache.tmp
)
del c:\files.cache >nul: 2>nul:
move c:\files.cache.tmp c:\files.cache
endlocal
```

You could do this with scheduled tasks either nightly (for an always-on server) or on boot (for a desktop). You could even make the script more intelligent to do it only every couple of days (I have an automated backup script that does a similar thing on the family machines I support). This creates the list in a temporary cache file then overwrites the original one to ensure the time when the file doesn't exist is minimized.

Then you can just use:

```
findstr \\ISTool.exe c:\files.cache
```

to locate all your files.

Comment: Ahh, but it's not in the path. I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: dir /b /s ISTool.exe works *kind of*. But it takes a prohibitive long time. It took 43 seconds on my current computer.

Comment: Have you thought of upgrading? :-) No, seriously, it has to search the entire disk so it will take a while. Is this the sort of thing you're going to be doing a lot of? If so, you may want to consider the idea of caching that information, see my update.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the really helpful answers here I hacked up these two batches which I thought I share here (I know this thread is now 3 years old, but its found as 1st match when googling ...):

1) which.bat:

```
@echo off
REM emulate the Linux which command
if "%1" == "" (
  echo Usage: %~nx0 ^<command[.ext]^>
  exit /b
)
setlocal
for %%P in (%PATHEXT%) do (
  for %%I in (%1 %1%%P) do (
    if exist "%%~$PATH:I" (
      echo %%~$PATH:I
      exit /b
    )
  )
)
```

not perfect because there are allways two tests, but its fast enough so I didnt further bother about; sure its possible to 1st do a separate test with %1 only ...

2) findfile.bat:

```
@echo off
REM emulate the Linux find command
if "%1" == "" (
  echo Usage: %~nx0 ^<startdir^> ^<file^>
  exit /b
)
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s %1\%2') do set F=%%A
if exist "%F%" echo %F%
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the closest I got. One drawback is that it works only for one drive per execution, but that could made more flexible. Another is the output, that always contains a `//` between the path and the filename. But per definition thats a valid path.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET filename=autoexec.bat

FOR /R C:\ %%a IN (\) DO (
   IF EXIST "%%a\%filename%" (

      SET fullpath=%%a%filename%
      GOTO break
   )
)
:break

ECHO %fullpath%
```

Will deliver: `C:\\autoexec.bat`

**EDIT:**

For explanation, the for loop iterates through all directories starting at the given path (C:\) and check if the filename exists in that directory. If so, both variables are concatenated and stored in %fullpath% and the loop is terminated by a jump.

Comment: thanks! I need to locate `tools\OpenCover.Console.exe` and `tools/net47/ReportGenerator.exe` from `"%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\OpenCover"` and `"%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\ReportGenerator"` respectively and this script helped

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this simple solution works, where you check to see if the output matches what you expect.  The first line runs the command and grabs the last line of standard output.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (' "xcopy /? 2> nul" ') do SET xcopyoutput=%%i
if "%xcopyoutput%"=="" echo xcopy not in path.
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, programs like [Everything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_%28software%29), and [UltraSearch](http://jam-software.com/ultrasearch) (freeware), [SwiftSearch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swiftsearch/) can search the MFT (of your NTFS partition) for files (so it can do so **very** quickly), (but Wikipedia claims this kind of thing can breach your security model by finding things it's not supposed to) -- some of them look like they have some command line parameters, I've not used them, but maybe it could be helpful, if you're resorting to a full drive search.