# How to get program full path in windows BAT?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I can get current bat file path by use %~dp0  .

but how to convert python.exe to "C:\Python27\python.exe" ?

Comment: Perhpas you mean something like this ==> [How do I find full path to an application in a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437457/how-do-i-find-full-path-to-an-application-in-a-batch-script)

Comment: the _where_ command may help you. **Type where /?** at the command prompt. Next you can fetch results using a _for_ loop

Comment: Eh, you posted that as a comment instead of an answer... not sure if at the same time I edited my answer.

Comment: @TylerY86 good synchronicity indeed ;-)

Comment: @elzooilogico see my OneLine bat where ^_^

Answer (score 1):

test.bat

```
@for %%i in (python.exe) do @set py=%%~$PATH:i
@echo %py%

@for %%i in ( %py%) do @set py=%%~dpi
@echo py's directory is %py%
```

OneLine bat whereis ==

where.bat

```
@for %%i in (%*) do @if not "%%~$PATH:i"=="" (echo %%~$PATH:i) else echo %%i

where ls.exe where.bat python.exe
D:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ls.exe
E:\sourceCode\shell\where.bat
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways;

```
call :label python.exe
:label
call %~dp$PATH:1
```

Or if you have `where` available ...

```
for /f %f in ('where python.exe') do %f
```

(You may need to use double percents [%%] in a batch file for this operation.)

If there are more than one executable on the path, you want something like...

```
set target=
for /f %f in ('where python.exe') do (
    set target=%f
)
call %target%
```

Comment: No，this is the bat file path，I  mean how to get command program full path....as a string